# Why do I have multiple linux image? How to remove one?

Tags: grub, kernel

When I was configuring grub, I found out that I have multiple linux image, like this,

[image: configure grub]

I checked with `uname -r` command, it showed `4.15.0-62-generic`

And then i checked on my `/boot` directory with `ls -l`, and the result is,

[image: /boot directory]

My questions are,

1. Do I have multiple linux (elementary OS) ?.
2. And if so, How to remove the duplicate ?.
3. Why when i checked with `uname -r` it's not showing the latest version (...-62) instead of (...-64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you don't. (You have as many Linux operating systems, as you have system root directories, which are usually marked with a forward slash, `/`.) The items in the list are not different operating systems, but different Linux kernel version images, available to your OS.
2. On how to remove older kernel versions, refer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu).
3. For some reason, newer kernel version hasn't been properly installed. (Despite newer kernel (.64) being available, your system still uses older version (.62). Try:

   `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, It's clear now

Comment: 7.62x25 of goodness in this answer.